# How to get to request parameters in Postman?

Tags: javascript, postman

In Postman tests how can one access some of the data of the request such as a query parameter?

One can access the request URL through the "request.url" object which returns a String. But is there a way in Postman to parse this URL string to access the query parameter(s)?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If you want to extract the query string in URL encoded format without parsing it. Here is how to do it:

```
pm.request.url.getQueryString() // example output: foo=1&bar=2&baz=3
```

Comment: hello, please what if I want to execute a script EVERY TIME the interceptor gets a post request and populate a js with the request params?? please, thank you

Comment: @Scaramouche I'm so sorry but I don't know how to do that. I think you should ask a separate question so that you can get some answers.

Answer (score 38):

The `pm.request.url.query.all()` array holds all query params as objects.
To get the parameters as a dictionary you can use:

```
var query = {};
pm.request.url.query.all().forEach((param) => { query[param.key] = param.value});
```

Comment: Worked for me - and this solution is really elegant :)

Comment: Thanks. This is perfect. This should be the accepted answer.

Comment: If you want to accomplish the same thing in a single line you can do `pm.request.url.query.all().reduce((paramObject, param) => ({...paramObject, [param.key]: param.value}), {})`

Comment: The above one-liner is not (or no longer) required. `pm.request.url.query.toObject()` will return the same simple hash without the bloat.

Answer (score 25):

I have been looking to access the **request params** for writing tests (in POSTMAN). I ended up parsing the `request.url` which is available in POSTMAN.

```
const paramsString = request.url.split('?')[1];
const eachParamArray = paramsString.split('&');
let params = {};
eachParamArray.forEach((param) => {
    const key = param.split('=')[0];
    const value = param.split('=')[1];
    Object.assign(params, {[key]: value});
});
console.log(params); // this is object with request params as key value pairs
```

[image: POSTMAN CLIENT]
[image: CONSOLE RESPONSE]

edit: Added [Github Gist](https://gist.github.com/sudarsangp/645eb33712ecfb3e21a66cfc3ab6d4dd)

Answer (score 14):

`pm.request.url.query` returns [PropertyList](http://www.postmanlabs.com/postman-collection/PropertyList.html) of [QueryParam](http://www.postmanlabs.com/postman-collection/QueryParam.html) objects. You can get one parameter `pm.request.url.query.get()` or all `pm.request.url.query.all()` for example. See `PropertyList` methods.

Answer (score 12):

Below one for postman 8.7 & up

```
var ref = pm.request.url.query.get('your-param-name');
```

Answer (score 9):

It's pretty simple - to access *YOUR_PARAM* value use
`pm.request.url.query.toObject().YOUR_PARAM`

Answer (score 5):

I don't think there's any out of box property available in Postman request object for query parameter(s).

Currently four properties are associated with 'Request' object:

**data {object}** - this is a dictionary of form data for the request. (request.data[“key”]==”value”)    **headers {object}** - this is a dictionary of headers for the request (request.headers[“key”]==”value”)    **method {string}** - GET/POST/PUT etc.
**url {string}** - the url for the request.

Source: https://www.getpostman.com/docs/sandbox

Answer (score 4):

Bit late to the party here, but I've been using the following to get an array of url query params, looping over them and building a key/value pair with those that are

```
// the message is made up of the order/filter etc params
// params need to be put into alphabetical order
var current_message = '';
var query_params = postman.__execution.request.url.query;
var struct_params = {};

// make a simple struct of key/value pairs
query_params.each(function(param){
    // check if the key is not disabled
    if( !param.disabled ) {
        struct_params[ param.key ] = param.value;
    }
});
```

so if my url is `example.com` then the array is empty and the structure has nothing, `{}`

if the url is `example.com?foo=bar` then the array contains

```
{
  description: {},
  disabled:false
  key:"foo"
  value:"bar"
}
```

and my structure ends up being `{ foo: 'bar' }`

Toggling the checkbox next to the property updates the `disabled` property:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I needed a way to programmatically detect if a query parameter was disabled in Postman's GUI. This worked just fine.

Answer (score 2):

have a look in the console doing :

```
console.log(request);
```

it'll show you all you can get from request. Then you shall access the different parameters using request., ie. request.name if you want the test name.
If you want a particular element in the url, I'm afraid you'll have to use some coding to obtain it (sorry I'm a beginner in javascript)

Hope this helps

Alexandre

Comment: Exaclty what i've been looking for. Just add to complete: this "request" returned request as string. So at this time you cannot do something like request.myparam. But, you can parse this request, for instance: 
    `let req = JSON.parse(request.data);`

and then you can get any of request parametres by req.myParam.   For instance testing between requests and response.

Answer (score 1):

Older post, but I've gotten this to work:

For some reason the debugger sees pm.request.url.query as an array with the items you want, but as soon as you try to get an item from it, its always null.  I.e. pm.request.url.query[0]  (or .get(0)) will return null, despite the debugger showing it has something at 0.

I have no idea why, but for some reason, it is not at index 0, despite the debugger claiming it is.  Instead, you need to filter the query first.  Such as this:

```
var getParamFromQuery = function (key)
{
    var x = pm.request.url.query;

    var newArr = x.filter(function(item){
        return item != null && item.key == key;
    });

    return newArr[0];
};

var getValueFromQuery = function (key)
{
    return getParamFromQuery(key).value;  
};

var paxid = getValueFromQuery("paxid");
```

getParamFromQuery returns the parameter with the fields for key, value and disabled.  getValueFromQuery returns just the value.

Answer (score 0):

You could also get querystring and set it as a global variable like this:

`postman.setGlobalVariable("SomeGlobalVariable",pm.request.url.query.get("queryParamName"));`

Answer (score 0):

You can access all parameters using `pm.request.url.query`. To retrieve a specific value, use `pm.request.url.query.get`. For more detailed information, you can obtain the parameter item using `pm.request.url.query.idx`. From the item, you can extract properties such as `disabled` and `key`.

Source:
1、[www.postmanlabs.com/postman-collection/Url](https://www.postmanlabs.com/postman-collection/Url.html)；
2、[www.postmanlabs.com/postman-collection/PropertyList](https://www.postmanlabs.com/postman-collection/PropertyList.html).