# How to get active only request query parameters in Postman?

Tags: postman

I know this has already answered in [How to get to request parameters in Postman?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44108015/how-to-get-to-request-parameters-in-postman)

with `pm.request.url.getQueryString()`

but it also returns the query parameters that's disabled (unchecked, not used)

I want the **real** query string that's **actually** sent with the requests, not all query parameters that I put on postman.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
console.log(pm.request.toJSON().url.query.filter((x)=>x.disabled!==true))
```

this will give query parameters that are not disabled.

Comment: thanks, that filter tricks following with map (to construct key=value formatted string) and join them with ampersand simplifies my script instead of iterating query using each and storing them in new object.

Answer (score 0):

here's what im doing rn

```
const queryStringList = {}
pm.request.url.query.each(param => {
    if (!param.disabled) {
        queryStringList[param.key] = param.value
    }
})
const queryString = Object.keys(queryStringList)
    .map(k => `${encodeURIComponent(k)}=${encodeURIComponent(queryStringList[k])}`)
    .join("&")
```

i'm basically iterating over all query parameters in dictionary form, and only picking the ones that's not disabled (unchecked) from my postman gui and rebuild it.